# Deploy content of pub folder using composer when installing a new Magento 2 module

Tags: magento2, module, extensions, composer, third-party-module

There are many modules that require to copy some files and folder inside the magento's "pub" folder. As our entire modules operations and infrastructure is based on composer, this manual (non-composer) copy/paste (merge) of pub folder is making a real pain for automation process ( I know we can use rsync command but I really wanted to do all operations based on composer from our private Satis repo, just don't like to manually copy paste contents of our pub folder to magento's pub folder).

I already tried composer's map functionality but as we are using "[Composer Custom Directory Installer](https://github.com/mnsami/composer-custom-directory-installer.git)" plugin for composer to install some 3rd party modules in app folder (as they are not working when installed under vendor folder), so map functionality is not work as expected.

```
{
    "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "version": "2.0.7",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
   "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/mnsami/composer-custom-directory-installer.git"
        },

        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://michel_gokan@bitbucket.org/rmecommerce/oshopblog.git"
        },
          {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://michel_gokan@bitbucket.org/rmecommerce/oshopall.git"
        },
         {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://michel_gokan@bitbucket.org/rmecommerce/oshopbasewidget.git"
        }
        ,
         {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://michel_gokan@bitbucket.org/rmecommerce/oshoppagebuilder.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://michel_gokan@bitbucket.org/rmecommerce/oshopmegamenu.git"
        },  
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://michel_gokan@bitbucket.org/rmecommerce/oshopproductlist.git"
        },  
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://michel_gokan@bitbucket.org/rmecommerce/oshopsetup.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://michel_gokan@bitbucket.org/rmecommerce/oshopthemesettings.git"
        },      
        {
          "type": "git",
          "url": "https://michel_gokan@bitbucket.org/rmecommerce/landryandarcaritheme.git"
        },
        {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://michel_gokan@bitbucket.org/rmecommerce/base.git"
        },
        {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://michel_gokan@bitbucket.org/rmecommerce/oshoptheme.git"
        },
        {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://michel_gokan@bitbucket.org/rmecommerce/pub.git"
        },
        {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://michel_gokan@bitbucket.org/rmecommerce/landryandarcaripub.git"
        }



    ],
    "require": {
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.0.7",
        "composer/composer": "@alpha",
        "mnsami/composer-custom-directory-installer": "*",
        "Ves/Blog":"*",
        "Ves/All":"*",
        "Ves/BaseWidget":"*",
        "Ves/PageBuilder":"*",
        "Ves/Megamenu":"*",
        "Ves/Productlist":"*",
        "Ves/Setup":"*",
        "Ves/Themesettings":"*",
        "magento/theme-frontend-oshop": "*",
        "magento/theme-frontend-base": "*",
        "magento/theme-frontend-Landryandarcari": "*",
        "RMI/pub":"*",
        "RMI/landry-arcari-pub":"*"

    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.5.3",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "2.3.*",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "2.2.2",
        "sjparkinson/static-review": "~4.1",
        "fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "~1.2",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.3 <=0.7.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "use-include-path": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": "app/code/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
        }
    },
   "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override",
        "installer-paths":{
      "./app/code/Ves/Blog/": ["Ves/Blog"],
      "./app/code/Ves/All/": ["Ves/All"],
      "./app/code/Ves/BaseWidget/": ["Ves/BaseWidget"],
      "./app/code/Ves/PageBuilder": ["Ves/PageBuilder"],
      "./app/code/Ves/Megamenu/": ["Ves/Megamenu"],
      "./app/code/Ves/Productlist/": ["Ves/Productlist"],
      "./app/code/Ves/Setup/": ["Ves/Setup"],
       "./app/code/Ves/Themesettings/": ["Ves/Themesettings"],


      "./app/design/frontend/Venustheme/oshop/": ["magento/theme-frontend-oshop"],
      "./app/design/frontend/RMI/Base/": ["magento/theme-frontend-base"],
      "./app/design/frontend/RMI/LandryAndArcari/": ["magento/theme-frontend-Landryandarcari"]

    }
    }
}
```

My goal is to install (merge) content of my module's pub folder with Magento 2's root pub folder when using `composer require mynamespace/mymodulename` command.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use below command for Pub content deploy :

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

**OR**
You may manually delete all file & folder of `/pub/static` except `htaccess` file